# Ask multiple directories dialog in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, directory

I am trying to select multiple folders. I need the equivalent of `askopenfilenames()` for directories, but only `askdirectory()` exists, which only allows to select one folder.

Previously I found a custom script that did this for Matlab (`uigetdir`). 
Any way of doing this in Python?

I need to batch process files in about 50 folders at a time, selecting them one by one is not realistic.

Also, I'm not a programmer, just trying to process my geophysical data, wouldn't be able to "code it myself" as I've seen suggested in other places. 
Would have thought such a basic thing would be included in the basic functions.

Comment: I don't know a whole lot about it, but a quick google search finds [this link](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tkinter-discuss/2011-January/002735.html). Have you done much (any) research?

Comment: @AdamSmith That's simply a loop that continues to `askdirectory`, that's not exactly what the OP wants.

Comment: @Rinzler I downvoted the question after the first result for `tkinter.askdirectory multiple directories` was a newsgroup posting with applicable code saying "There's not really a better way to do this, but here's a bit of kludge for a hack." The downvote is there for "This question does not show any research effort."

Comment: I think there's no such a function to `askdirectories` in the standard libraries, but I think it could be somehow implemented.

Comment: @Rinzler if you'd like to spend the time to implement it, feel free to fork tkinter and do so

Comment: @AdamSmith How can he show some effort, if it there's nothing useful regarding the topic around the web?

Comment: @Rinzler There ***is*** useful information. The *first hit* from a google search is a page saying "There's no function to do that: here's how to work around it." I linked it, and we've talked about it several times....

Comment: @AdamSmith This question deserves upvotes, in order to encourage people to implement such a dialog, in my modest opinion. It's easy to say no, and give workarounds.

Comment: @Rinzler get going on the implementation, then! Sounds like it would be a great addition to the module. I'll add a sizeable bounty if you can implement one.

Comment: I did find that link, however it is from 2011, I hoped that in the last 4 years it would have been implemented, especially since it is now Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

Having had the same problem I developed my own solution. With this you can select one directory at a time then select cancel when you are finished.

The function the returns a list of the directories you have selected.

```
def fun_directory_selector(request_string: str, selected_directory_list: list, search_directory):
    directory_path_string = filedialog.askdirectory(initialdir=search_directory, title=request_string)

       if len(directory_path_string) > 0:
        selected_directory_list.append(directory_path_string)
        fun_directory_selector('Select the next Directory or Cancel to end', 
                               selected_directory_list,
                               os.path.dirname(directory_path_string))

    return selected_directory_list
```

Answer (score 0):

The OP asked for a solution with Tkinter which isn't available but a solution is possible with wxPython-Phoenix

```
####### Retrieve a list of directories with wxPython-Phoenix   - tested on python3.5
### installation instruction for wxPython-Phoenix  : https://wiki.wxpython.org/How%20to%20install%20wxPython#Installing_wxPython-Phoenix_using_pip
### modified from : https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.lib.agw.multidirdialog.html
import os
import wx
import wx.lib.agw.multidirdialog as MDD

# Our normal wxApp-derived class, as usual
app = wx.App(0)
dlg = MDD.MultiDirDialog(None, title="Custom MultiDirDialog", defaultPath=os.getcwd(),  # defaultPath="C:/Users/users/Desktop/",
                         agwStyle=MDD.DD_MULTIPLE|MDD.DD_DIR_MUST_EXIST)

if dlg.ShowModal() != wx.ID_OK:
    print("You Cancelled The Dialog!")
    dlg.Destroy()


paths = dlg.GetPaths()

#Print directories' path and files 
for path in enumerate(paths):
    print(path[1])
    directory= path[1].replace('OS (C:)','C:')
    print(directory)
    for file in os.listdir(directory):
        print(file)

dlg.Destroy()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: I get an error saying `there is a mismatch between C/C++ and Windows locale`. What is happening???!!!